# Undefined function mysql error using IIS7, PHP 5.6 and MySql 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

I am very new to php and mysql and I am getting an undefined function when trying to connect to a mysql database.  I am running on a Windows 2008 R2 server with IIS 7 and I installed PHP 5.6 and MySql using the Web Platform installer.

Now in researching this, I ran a script that shows the loaded extensions and I have come to the conclusion that the php_mysql.dll extension is not loading even though it is in the php.ini and is not commented out.  The phpinfo() script shows that php appears to be running properly and in the C:\Program Files(x86)\PHP\5.6 directory and that the ext folder (extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\") is also shown in the php.ini.  Finally, the PHP installation folder is in the PATH environment variable.

Any other suggestions as to why this extension is not loading would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: double check which php.ini file is being loaded. You can view it in `phpinfo()`. Also, is `mysqli` installed? Because you should really be using that instead. Especially if you are learning, you might as well learn right and bind variables.

Comment: Unless you're trying to work on a legacy application you shouldn't be using `mysql_query` and related functions, so loading `php_mysql` is a bad idea. Why MySQL 5.1? The current version is 5.6.

Comment: I have verified that the php.ini being loaded has the phpmysql.dll in the extensions. @Jonathan, I did not install mysqli but that extension is in the php.ini.

Comment: @tadman, I used the MS WPI and 5.1 is what it installed.  I will look at upgrading to 5.6.

Comment: My point was to make sure that the phpinfo file is pointing to the same php.ini file you are editing. If there is more than one php.ini file, php has it's own precedence as to which it will load and it might not be super obvious. So you might be editing one and php loading another.

Comment: I have verified the php.ini file being referenced in the phpinfo() is C:\Program Files (X86)\PHP\5.6\php.ini and that is the  file that has the the php_mysql.dll, php_mysqli.dll listed in the extensions and are not commented out.

Comment: I should also add that the mysql and mysqli extension are enabled in the php manager of IIS.

Comment: I solved the problem.  There was a syntax error earlier in the php.ini that was preventing those other extensions from loading.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should be able to grab MySQL 5.6 directly from the [main download link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Comment: Thanks tadman, I have upgraded with the webinstaller.  Cheers